# munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer Error while making an Array data structure in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management

I tried going through many similar questions regarding `munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer` errors, but I'm stuck as to what to do. I tried adding `free` commands too.

I'm a C++ novice and normally use Python and Java, so the whole concept of pointers and memory management are new to me. It would be great if someone can explain what I'm doing wrong.

Here is my code for my Array class for a generic T:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
template <typename T>
class Array {
    private:
        T *arr;
        int len = 0; //length the user thinks the array is
        int capacity = 0; //actual array capacity
    public:
        Array(int cap=16){
            if (cap<0){
                throw invalid_argument("Illegal Capacity: "+cap);
            }
            capacity = cap;
            arr = new T[cap];
            for(int i=0; i<capacity; i++){
                arr[i] = 0;
            }
            
        }
        ~Array(){ delete [] arr; }
        T& operator[](int index){ return arr[index]; }
        
        int size(){ return len; }
        
        bool isEmpty(){ return size() == 0; }

        T get(int index){ return arr[index]; }
        
        void set(int index, T elem){ arr[index] = elem; }
        
        void clear(){
            for(int i = 0; i < capacity; i++)
                arr[i] = 0;
            len = 0;
        }
        void add(T elem){
            if (len+1 > capacity){
                if (capacity == 0) capacity = 1;
                else capacity*=2;
                T *newarr = new T[capacity];
                for (int i = 0; i < len; i++){
                    newarr[i] = arr[i];
                }
                delete [] arr;
                arr = newarr;
            }
            arr[len++]=elem;
        }
        T removeAt(int rmIndex){
            if (rmIndex >= len || rmIndex < 0) throw out_of_range(rmIndex +" out of range for len " + len);
            T data = arr[rmIndex];
            T *newarr = new T[len-1];
            for (int i=0, j=0; i < len; i++, j++){
                if (i==rmIndex){
                    j--;
                }
                else{
                    newarr[j]=arr[i];
                }
            }
            delete [] arr;
            arr = newarr;
            capacity = --len;
            return data;
        }
        bool remove(T t){
            for (int i=0; i<len; i++){
                if (arr[i]==t){
                    removeAt(i);
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
        int indexOf(T t){
            for (int i=0; i<len; i++){
                if (arr[i]==t){
                    return i;
                }
            }
            return -1;
        }
        bool contains(T t){ return indexOf(t) != -1; }
};
int main()
{
    cout << "hello" <<endl;
    Array<float>z(122);
    cout << z.size() << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < z.size(); i++){
        z.set(i,(float)i);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < z.size(); i++){
        cout << z.get(i);
    }
    cout << z.size() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The output is only `hello world` without anything else.

I have been learning from [this video](https://youtu.be/RBSGKlAvoiM?t=1750) and I'm trying to convert the Java code given there into C++ in an attempt to learn the language and I've been using StackOverflow extensively for it. For this issue though, I'm unable to find the source of the problem, so please do help me.

The Java code from which this is trying to be adapted into C++ is available [here](https://github.com/williamfiset/DEPRECATED-data-structures/blob/master/com/williamfiset/datastructures/dynamicarray/DynamicArray.java).

Comment: Note: I am using the namespace `std` and have included `iostream`

Comment: How to get the `munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer`? The template Array is never used in the code.

Comment: `delete[]` and neither `delete` nor `free` must follow `new[]`.

Comment: You should post [mcve]. You should have learned stackoverflow user's guide, right?

Comment: @S.M. very sorry, have edited it in

Comment: `arr` is being used uninitialized.

Comment: @anastaciu It is initialized in the constructor right?

Comment: By the way, the line `throw invalid_argument("Illegal Capacity: "+cap);` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: Look at the condition and braces carefully. `arr` is never initialized, the `arr = ` is not reachable.

Comment: The loop body in main is never executed, size is zero.

Comment: Tell me, is `cap` < 0? You probably missplaced a brace.

Comment: Yes I fixed that brace and now it compiles and executes, but the array doesn't work.

Comment: You need to be more specific, note that a debugger is a coder's best friend (one of them at least).

Comment: @anastaciu Valgrind gives very cryptic output... Do you suggest something else?

Comment: Now I added a for loop in main which prints the elements stored, but there is no output. Also, trying to cout the size of the array has no output.

Comment: valgrind is not a debugger, you can use gdb, here is an online one https://onlinegdb.com/ELX4QmDgb

Comment: Fork the project, you'll have a ***debug*** option, then you can set your breakpoints and run through the code.

Comment: As @S.M. said, your `size()` function is returning zero, because you are not setting the `len` member in your constructor. Also, your destructor should be using `delete[]`.

Comment: @jkb Exactly and that's the whole issue. I've been able to get the output working with manually entering 122 instead of z.size(). Thanks a lot for all the help. Feel free to post this as an answer, and I hope these comments are of some use to anyone who has this issue later.

Comment: Yes, there's a problem in the logic itself. `len` needs to be updated every time something is set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `size()` function depends on the `len` member being set, which it was not.

You should also be aware that the expression `"Illegal Capacity: " + cap` does not append the value of `cap` to the end of the string. It does pointer arithmetic and if `cap` is less than zero you will be constructing the exception with a pointer to memory *before* the beginning of the string literal.

Comment: What exactly will happen if I do send cap<0?

Comment: Fixed that with "Illegal Capacity: "+std::to_string(cap)

Comment: Make sure you do something similar when you throw `out_of_range` in your `removeAt` function.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @S.M. @anastaciu and @jkb for their guidance.

The original code posted here was:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
template <typename T>
class Array {
 private:
  T *arr;
  int len = 0;
  int capacity = 0;

 public:
  Array(int cap = 16) {
    if (cap < 0) {
      throw invalid_argument("Illegal Capacity: " + cap);
    }
    capacity = cap;
    arr = new T[cap];
    for (int i = 0; i < capacity; i++) {
      arr[i] = 0;
    }
  }
  ~Array() { delete arr; }
  T &operator[](int index) { return arr[index]; }

  int size() { return len; }

  bool isEmpty() { return size() == 0; }

  T get(int index) { return arr[index]; }

  void set(int index, T elem) { arr[index] = elem; }

  void clear() {
    for (int i = 0; i < capacity; i++) arr[i] = 0;
    len = 0;
  }
  void add(T elem) {
    if (len + 1 > capacity) {
      if (capacity == 0)
        capacity = 1;
      else
        capacity *= 2;
      T *newarr = new T[capacity];
      for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        newarr[i] = arr[i];
      }
      free(arr);
      arr = newarr;
    }
    arr[len++] = elem;
  }
  T removeAt(int rmIndex) {
    if (rmIndex >= len || rmIndex < 0)
      throw out_of_range(rmIndex + " out of range for len " + len);
    T data = arr[rmIndex];
    T *newarr = new T[len - 1];
    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < len; i++, j++) {
      if (i == rmIndex) {
        j--;
      } else {
        newarr[j] = arr[i];
      }
    }
    free(arr);
    arr = newarr;
    capacity = --len;
    return data;
  }
  bool remove(T t) {
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      if (arr[i] == t) {
        removeAt(i);
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
  int indexOf(T t) {
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      if (arr[i] == t) {
        return i;
      }
    }
    return -1;
  }
  bool contains(T t) { return indexOf(t) != -1; }
};
int main() {
  Array<float> z(122);
  for (int i = 0; i < z.size(); i++) {
    z.set(i, (float)i);
    std::cout << z[i];
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Whenever `new []` is used, it needs to be paired with a `delete []`. `free` and `delete` should not be used. That is the first issue here, but that's not what causes the code to not work.

The main code never initializes `len` and hence when the `size()` function is used, it returns `0`, and hence the `for loop` is never entered.

The `len` needs to be updated every time something is `set` as well.

Thus, the main issue is in the logic itself.